# understanding the lower bound/ upper bound interface

Tags: c++, interface, lower-bound

I am having trouble grasping the semantics of the lower/ upper bound interface.

Consider this test snippet I wrote:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

  // sorted vector
  std::vector<std::pair<size_t, std::vector<int>>> v = {
      std::make_pair(0, std::vector<int>()),
      std::make_pair(0, std::vector<int>()),
      std::make_pair(3, std::vector<int>()),
      std::make_pair(3, std::vector<int>()),
      std::make_pair(5, std::vector<int>()),
      std::make_pair(20, std::vector<int>())};

  auto key = 3;
  auto itr = std::lower_bound(
      v.begin(), v.end(), key,
      [](const auto &t1, const size_t d) -> bool { return t1.first < d; });

  std::cout << itr->first << "\n";
}
```

Why do I not need two vector elements? Why do I need only one and a second argument (`d`) of the type of `key`? What is `d` anyway? The documentation sounded like it is a vector element cast to type of `key`. But why then not accept another vector element as the second argument? And why does no comparison against `key` happen?

Why does the interface not look like this:

```
auto itr = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 3, [](const auto& t1, const
  auto& t2) -> bool {return t1.first < t2.first;});
```

Can you explain the semantics behind the parameters, especially `d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4th argument of `lower_bound` is the definition of `<` between the **element** in the container and your **key**.

```
auto itr = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 3, [](const auto& t1, const
  auto& t2) -> bool {return t1.first < t2.first;});
```

With this, `lower_bound` is only aware of the `<` relationship between elements (i.e. `{int, vector<int>}`) in the array, but know nothing about the relationship between **element** and the **key**. Thus `lower_bound` cannot find the key, because it just don't know the **rule** to compare!

`d` is here passed as `key`, i.e. `3` every time for comparison. It is equal to

```
auto it = std::lower_bound(
    v.begin(), v.end(), key,
    [key](const auto &t1, const size_t whatever) -> bool { return t1.first < key; }
);
```

Check more on the code from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/).

---

1. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/

Answer (score 0):

Lower bound guarantees it only passes `key` as the right hand argument.

It does a binary search, looking for the place where `comp(e,key)` changes from true to false.  If it is `comp(e,key)` is true at a specific element `e`, it searches the later elements, if false the earlier elements, until it has found the "edge" between the elements "kess than" key and the elements "greater than" key.  It does this via binary search: so first middle of the iterator range, then middle of the range it wants to search next, recursively.

It then returns the iterator to the earliest element `e` such that `!comp(e,key)` is true.

This only works if all the elements `e` such that `comp(e,key)` are at the start of the list.